# Highcharts Tooltip Show Arrow/Caret when followPointer flag is on

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I am trying to have Highcharts cartesian charts show the caret/arrow on my tooltip despite having `followPointer` turned on.

Reading the docs, the one way to show the caret is to turn `followPointer` off. However, for my uses, it would be ideal if I could have it on for all situations as well.

I tried checking the source code for Tooltips [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=followPointer&type=) to see how `followPointer` code is implemented, perhaps it would tell me a little whether there's a flag that switches the arrow on or off, but it doesn't seem like I can find anything of this sorts.

If you need, here's a fiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/Malinga/oo2njkhs/2/

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/9wszk15v/)

You basically need to override the `move` method implemented in Highcharts to set `skipAnchor` to `false`.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'move', function(proceed, x, y, anchorX, anchorY) {
    var tooltip = this,
      now = tooltip.now,
      animate = tooltip.options.animation !== false && !tooltip.isHidden &&
      // When we get close to the target position, abort animation and land on the right place (#3056)
      (Math.abs(x - now.x) > 1 || Math.abs(y - now.y) > 1),
      skipAnchor = tooltip.followPointer || tooltip.len > 1;

    skipAnchor = false;

    // Get intermediate values for animation
    H.extend(now, {
      x: animate ? (2 * now.x + x) / 3 : x,
      y: animate ? (now.y + y) / 2 : y,
      anchorX: skipAnchor ? undefined : animate ? (2 * now.anchorX + anchorX) / 3 : anchorX,
      anchorY: skipAnchor ? undefined : animate ? (now.anchorY + anchorY) / 2 : anchorY
    });

    // Move to the intermediate value
    tooltip.getLabel().attr(now);


    // Run on next tick of the mouse tracker
    if (animate) {

      // Never allow two timeouts
      clearTimeout(this.tooltipTimeout);

      // Set the fixed interval ticking for the smooth tooltip
      this.tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        // The interval function may still be running during destroy,
        // so check that the chart is really there before calling.
        if (tooltip) {
          tooltip.move(x, y, anchorX, anchorY);
        }
      }, 32);

    }
  });
}(Highcharts));
```